# asp .net dropdownlist autopostback not working with IE11

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist working in all browser but only in IE11 its not working while Autopostback=true.

After searching on this forum I came to know that there is some files to be updated in App_Browser folder which I have also updated but still its not working. I have updated the App_Browser files from here

> http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Here is the code:

Dropdownlist in Default7.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsCallback)
        {
            filldropdown1(ddl1);

        }
    }



public static void filldropdown1(DropDownList objDDL)
    {
        string strSql = "select DISTINCT(Roll_no),Roll_no from subject_details";
        objDDL = FillingDDL(strSql, objDDL);
    }

public static DropDownList FillingDDL(string strSql, DropDownList objCmb)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        SqlDataAdapter objDa = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, con);
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            objDa.Fill(objDs);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            objDa.Dispose();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            objCmb.DataSource = objDs;
            objCmb.DataTextField = objDs.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName;
            objCmb.DataValueField = objDs.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName;
            objCmb.DataBind();
        }
        //objCmb.Items.Insert(0, "Select here");
        return objCmb;
    }


    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>

in Default7.aspx.cs

    protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ddl1value = ddl1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            // fillDropdown2(ddl2, ddl1value);
            string ddl2value = ddl2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            // fillDropdown3(ddl3, ddl2value);
            SqlConnection objConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand objCmd2;
            SqlDataReader objRdr2;
            //  String strCmd2;
            objConn2.Open();




            objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subject_details WHERE Roll_no = " +
            "'" + ddl1value + "'", objConn2);
            objRdr2 = objCmd2.ExecuteReader();


            while (objRdr2.Read())
            {
                Label122.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Name"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label12.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label11.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address1"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label123.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address2"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label121.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address3"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label111.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address4"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label1.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address5"].ToString().ToUpper();

                Label7.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address11"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label8.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address6"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label9.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address7"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label13.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address8"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label14.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address9"].ToString().ToUpper();
                Label15.InnerText = (string)objRdr2["Address10"].ToString().ToUpper();


            }

            if (ddl1value == "Other")
            {
                lbl2.Visible = true;
                TextBox2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lbl2.Visible = false;
                TextBox2.Visible = false;
            }

            objRdr2.Close();
            objConn2.Close();

        }
```

Any help on this is welcome

Comment: post the dropdownlist source markup

Comment: How are you adding/binding List items to Dropdownlist, can you also post generated HTML?

Comment: @AnilKumar yes have added that too

Comment: In IE11 it never works or it does not work after populating via callback, and is this Dropdown is inside an update panel?

Comment: @AnilKumar...have tried with removing Call Back...but still no luck surprisingly in IE11 asp.net validations are also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally searching enough in this forum i got the solution by updating the code in ie.browser of App_Browser folder...the following code I have used...

```
<browsers>
<browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
<identification>
  <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
  <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
</identification>
<capture>
  <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
</capture>
<capabilities>
  <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
  <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
  <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
  <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
  <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
  <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
  <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
  <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
  <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
  <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
  <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
</capabilities>
 </browser>

<!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
<browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
<identification>
  <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
</identification>

<capabilities>
  <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
  <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
  <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
  <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
  <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
  <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
  <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
  <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
  <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
  <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
  <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
  <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
  <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
  <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
  <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
</capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh your Drop Down using Javascript or JQuery
Have you check this in another version of IE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#dropDownId").change(function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
   });
});
```